# Dots in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I need dots between chapter titles and page numbers in TOC. By default part and chapter do not have dots... I tried to look at tocloft package but could not figure it out how to do it. Thanks

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[
twoside=true,
paperwidth=115mm, paperheight=195mm,
textheight=15.5cm,
textwidth=8.5cm,
left=1.3cm,
right=1.7cm,
top=1.7cm,
bottom=2.2cm
]
    {geometry}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}

 \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: To also change the part-entries, additionally redefine `\cftpartdotsep` same like `\cftchapterdotsep` in [Peter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515271/277964).

Comment: Yes it does! Sorry I did not find the answer myself...